# Clustered index in django

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-models, clustered-index

I have two tables in my models:

1)Owner:

```
OwnerName
```

2)Car

```
OwnerKey

CarName

CarPrice
```

Here while creating a row in Owner table, I also add the Cars for that owner Car table. So all the cars for a particular owner are stored sequentially in the Car table.Now if I want to ask whether should I use cluster indexing or not? Once the cars for a particular owner are saved, no cars are then added for that owner neither any car is deleted, just the price is changed. What should I do for a faster access? And how to implement cluster index via django?

Comment: It doesn't mention any sort of cluster indexing @madzohan

Comment: regular indexes wont work for you?

Comment: Clustering will make the retrieval speedy. Am I right?

Comment: Thats what indexes are for!

Comment: But I need clustering, regular indexes wont do that well @cold_coder

Comment: Clustered indexed thats what is better in my case. can you please help? @miki725

Answer (score 1):

You question is asking for information that requires studying the SQL, not just the Django code.

If you have only a thousand owners and cars, things will probably be fast enough.  If you have a million owners or cars, you need indexes, not necessarily "clustered".

A "clustered" key is implemented in MySQL as a `PRIMARY KEY`.  You can have only one per table, and its values must be unique.

I Django, do something like this to get a PK:

```
column1 = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
```

Please provide the table schema you already have.  That is, go beyond Django and get `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  (What you have provided is too vague; hence my answer is too vague.)

References:

- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8316
- [Two primary keys specified in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754772/two-primary-keys-specified-in-mysql-database)  -- It's really talking about having a "composite" `PRIMARY KEY`.

There are no "clustered" indexes other than the `PRIMARY KEY`.  However, a secondary key can have similar performance *if* it is a "covering index".  That term refers to an index that contains all the columns that are found in the `SELECT`.  *Also*, the columns are ordered correctly.

Let's see your `SELECT` statements in order to better judge what is needed.

Comment: But I am using QuerySets API here,not the raw queries