# Is there any possibility to have two PK on one table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I am really surprised that the table having two PK columns.

When I am trying to add PK on another column then those two PK columns changed as normal and only one column changed to PK.

Below is the script it was given

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductionPlaning] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductionPlaning] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductionPlaningId] ASC,
    [Date] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: A table can never have more than one PK. However, a PK can consist of several columns.

Comment: This doesn't have two Primary Keys. It has one primary key formed by two fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two primary keys specified in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754772/two-primary-keys-specified-in-mysql-database)

Answer (score 4):

By definition, a primary key is one or more fields that uniquely identifies a record in a database table. Therefore, you cannot have two separate primary keys for the same table.

If you just want the field to be unique, you simply make it a unique field by adding a unique constraint to it `ALTER TABLE YourTableNAme
ADD UNIQUE (Date);`

If you want the both ProductionPlanningId and Date to be the unique identifiers for your table; you make a composite primary key:

```
ALTER table TABLE_NAME
 ADD CONSTRAINT [name of your PK, e.g. PK_TableName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(column1, column2, etc.)
```

Comment: " a primary key is a field" is contradicted by your later example of a composite primary key. A primary key is *one or more* columns.

Comment: By definition a primary key is a combination of one _or more_ columns that uniquely identify a row in a table. A primary key is not limited to a single column.

Answer (score 3):

The create script describes the situation.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductionPlaning] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductionPlaning] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductionPlaningId] ASC,
    [Date] ASC
)
```

As you see, the PK is created by two columns (`ProductionPlaningId` and `Date`) so there is no multiple different PK in the table. It is not possible.

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 1):

A table can never have more than one Primary  Key. However, a Primary  Key can consist of several columns.In you example Primary key is made with more than one column .

Answer (score 0):

A primary key is defined as one or more columns with the following properties:

1. The combination of values is unique.
2. None of the values is ever NULL.
3. Only one such set is called "primary".

Other sets are called *candidate primary keys*.  A table can have any number of candidates, and you can even declare them as being `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE`.  However, the *primary* in "primary key" means "one".

By default SQL Server actually sorts the data on the data pages using the primary key (this is called a "clustered" index).  The data is only stored once, so it can only be sorted once, further emphasizing the one-ness of the primary key.

That said, your question is really about *composite primary keys*.  These are primary keys that have more than one column.  In general, I avoid composite primary keys, preferring a synthetic identity column as a primary key.  However, they are definitely allowed and sometimes useful.